# Find $3 \log(\sqrt{x}\log x) = 56, \log_{\log (x)}(x) = 54$ in base $b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, proof-writing, contest-math

Solve the following:

In a Martian civilization, all logarithms whose bases are not specified are assumed to be base $b$, for some fixed $b \geq 2$. A Martian student writes down
\begin{align*}3 \log(\sqrt{x}\log x) &= 56\\\log_{\log (x)}(x) &= 54
\end{align*}and finds that this system of equations has a single real number solution $x > 1$. Find $b$

My progress:

Let $\log_bx=c$.
So $\log_cx=54\implies x=c^{54}$. Also $$3\log(\sqrt{x}\log x) =56\implies 3\log(\sqrt{x})+3\log(x) =56\implies 3\log_b(\sqrt{x})+3c=56.$$

By base changing formula, we get $$\log_b(\sqrt{x})=\frac{\log_c{\sqrt{x}}}{\log_cb}=27\cdot \log_bc=27\cdot \frac{\log_xc}{\log_xb}=27\cdot \frac{1}{54}\cdot c=\frac{c}{2}.$$

So $$\frac{3c}{2}+3c=56\implies c=\frac{56\times 2}{9}.$$

But actually, $c=36$. So please help me find the mistake in my proof.

Comment: More simply, $\log_b \sqrt x =\frac 12\times \log_b x=\frac c2$ as before, no change of basis needed.  But it is not true  that $3\log (\sqrt x\,\log x)=3\log \sqrt x +3\log x$.

Comment: As @lulu said, it should be $3log(\sqrt{x} )+ 3 log( log( x))$ rather than $3 log (\sqrt{x}) + 3 log (x)$.

Comment: @lulu why? log(xy)=log(x)+log(y). I used that

Comment: OH! I got it! Thankyou!

Comment: We have  $3\log (\sqrt x\,\log x)=3\log \sqrt x +3\log (\log x)=\frac 32\times c+3\log c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

Using identity

$$\log_{~~q} ~p=\frac{\log p}{\log q}$$

for any base. Next recast and solve

$$ u=log \sqrt x, v=log ~log x~ $$

$$ u+v=\frac{56}{3},~ \frac{u}{v}=27. $$

Comment: Thankyou got it!